# How can nginx serve static files on a subdirectory and pass the rest to uwsgi?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I've got a directory `example.com/data/` that is only served static content at root (i.e. `example.com/data/` serves a static webpage, but `example.com/data/file` is served by a script). I'm using uwsgi to serve the static portion, and have managed to get my script to serve content on its own, but I can't figure out what rules I need to get this behavior because I'm getting an "500 Internal Server Error."

My current (nonworking) configuration looks like:

```
location = /data/ {
  alias /srv/data/index.html;
}
location /data {
  gzip off;
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_modifier1 9;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/data.sock;
}
```

I've tried a few configurations with `try_files`, but I can't seem to make it work. Do I need to reference one of the directories here differently or use try_files and some named routes somehow?

EDIT: Thanks to @Richard Smith, this configuration works:

```
location = /data/ {
  root /srv/data/;
  try_files /index.html =404;
}
location = /data {
  gzip off;
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_modifier1 9;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/data.sock;
}
```

Comment: Are there any entries in the error log?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes. It says " "/srv/data/index.htmlindex.html" is not a directory". But when I tried to change it to "alias /srv/data/;", it went straight to uwsgi, and "alias /srv/data;" gives 403 Forbidden (presumably because it can't give a directory listing).

Comment: Try: `location = /data/ { root /srv/data/; try_files /index.html =404; }`